# C++ simple open file dialog in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, dialog

I was wondering if anyone could help me out on implementing a simple file open dialog in C++ in Ubuntu. I am using OpenGL for my GUI, but I would like the user to be able to select a file when the program loads. I have tried gtkmm and wxWidgets but they seem to be too complicated for what I want to do.

Comment: gtkmm and wxWidgets both come with premade file chooser dialogs. Does it get much simpler than that? In what way are those too complicated for you?

Comment: what I mean is that both openGl and gtk need their own main loops to be running at the same time, and I don't know how to integrate both of them. thanks for the response

Comment: Why "at the same time"? You say you need to select a file *when the program loads* so theoretically you could even have a separate gtkmm program for the file chooser that then passes the file name as a command line parameter to your OpenGL app.

Comment: oh I mean that the user should be able to load a file when it starts but also at any time during the use of the program. but that does make sense.

Comment: Simplest way: `popen()` on `zenity --file-selection`

Answer (score 9):

If you just need to select a file, then launch a separate program to do that. Like @Dummy00001 said in the comment, you can start `zenity --file-selection` as a child process and read its stdout.

```
char filename[1024];
FILE *f = popen("zenity --file-selection", "r");
fgets(filename, 1024, f);
```

Or you can also write your own program to do the task. That way you can customize the UI as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [osdialog](https://github.com/AndrewBelt/osdialog) for this purpose. See `osdialog_gtk2.c` for an example using GTK+ 2.

Answer (score 1):

This project can help you:
https://github.com/samhocevar/portable-file-dialogs

It uses the same idea described in these answers but it is architecture agnostic and for Unix it wraps zenity, kdialog ...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have more complete code with zenity:

```
const char zenityP[] = "/usr/bin/zenity";
char Call[2048];

sprintf(Call,"%s  --file-selection --modal --title=\"%s\" ", zenityP, "Select file");

FILE *f = popen(Call,"r");
fgets(Bufor, size, f); 

int ret=pclose(f);
if(ret<0) perror("file_name_dialog()");

return ret==0;//return true if all is OK
```